# No separation between column headers and first row of data

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list view in WinForms that works and looks fine. However, the grid lines are formatted in such a way that there's no separation between the column headers and the first row of data. This makes it look like the first row of data is part of the column headers. You can see what I mean here:

[image]

Is there any way I can format the list to stop this from happening, and make it look 'proper'? Thanks for any help.

Comment: WPF or WinForms?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying... WinForms. Will update.

Comment: Well... i have tried to find a property but did not found such property..very strange, why not to use `DataGridView` ? it is more improved control then a ListView.

Comment: The visual appearance of `ListView` is dictated by the user's selected Visual Style (Theme) and cannot be controlled in WinForms unless you manually paint the column headers yourself. (Note that since Windows 8, users cannot change Windows' Visual Style - compare with Windows XP which had Classic, 3 colors for Luna (Blue, Green, and Silver), "Royale Noir", Media Center Theme, and the Zune theme.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're displaying "data" to users in a grid - except you're using a `ListView` - which is really intended for filesystem display, not data.

I recommend you switch to using `DataGridView` (avoid `System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid` as it's older and doesn't let you (easily) control the data being displayed).

Also, protip for usability: if a table cell contains numeric data then it should be formatted with Right alignment, otherwise give it a Left alignment - avoid Middle/Center alignment in non-header table cells as it makes it difficult to visually scan a table.

Comment: I considered using a `DataGridView`, but it seems as though it requires data binding from something like a database, however I'm just pulling data from text files so I don't know how I'd bind it to the `DataGridView`

Comment: @KianStevens You don't need to use data-binding, you can manually add to the `DataGridview.Rows` and `Row.Cells` collections - whereas with `DataGrid` (not `DataGridView`) you can only do it with binding.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will consider implementing it, however, the `ListView` seems to work pretty well too (apart from the problem I have above!)